# CAS Maven Overlay And Spring Boot do not work together

Tags: maven, spring-boot, cas

I create a spring boot application from spring.io, then add CAS dependecy to pom file of project as below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

after that start spring boot application, but CAS does not start in spring boot application.
what is the main problem in this usage of CAS?
Is the method of using the CAS at this way wrong?

### _____________________________________________________________

finaly I solve my problem. I change the pom file as below

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <javaparser-core.version>3.12.0</javaparser-core.version>
    <start.class>org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication</start.class>
    <start.class2>x.y.sso.SingleSignOnApplication</start.class2>
    <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
    <cas.version>6.0.1</cas.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
        <version>${javaparser-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-core-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-core-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${cas.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>cas</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start.class2}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!--<recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>-->
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <manifestFile>
                        ${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp-tomcat/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                    </manifestFile>
                </archive>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

then I create a Application class

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    JerseyAutoConfiguration.class,
    JmxAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
    RedisAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
    CassandraAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CasConfigurationProperties.class})
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableScheduling  
public class SingleSignOnApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(SingleSignOnApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

by this configuration, build maven goal and execution project by spring boot work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

CAS is already a spring boot web application. Therefor have a look into cas-server-webapp-init-6.0.1.jar and look CasWebApplication.java.

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JerseyAutoConfiguration.class, GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, JmxAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class, RedisAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, CassandraAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CasConfigurationProperties.class})
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
@EnableScheduling
public class CasWebApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, Object> properties = CasEmbeddedContainerUtils.getRuntimeProperties(Boolean.TRUE);
    Banner banner = CasEmbeddedContainerUtils.getCasBannerInstance();
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(new Class[] { CasWebApplication.class })
      .banner(banner)
      .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
      .properties(properties)
      .logStartupInfo(true)
      .contextClass(CasWebApplicationContext.class)
      .run(args);
  }
}
```

**Remove** the **spring-boot-starter dependencies** and CAS should start itself as a web application.

For further investigation I would recommend you to download the war from https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp/6.0.1/war and inspect it with a tool like jd-gui.

Comment: Can I start CAS in a spring boot application? I want develop a project for wrapping the CAS and add extra entities to project. (I do not want execute two war projects, that one of them is the CAS and the other is my project)

Comment: You have the source code, you can do anything. But i would not underestimate the amount of work. Already your request sounds like you are doing something wrong if you want to put an extra application into a SSO-server.

Comment: thank you for your answer, exactly I want add authorization to CAS for my application, so I need create an application that contains CAS project.

Comment: Are you sure you need a CAS Server and not a CAS-Client to talk to a server? https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client